# VIJAVA: Get exact list of VM's asked for instead of sorting through ALL

Tags: java, virtual-machine, vmware, vsphere

Is there any way through vijava to get the exact list of VM's I want whilst also getting their "type info" (e.g. runtime, config, guest objects)? Currently you have to go through InventoryNavigator which grabs all listed VM's and iterates through until it finds the one which matches the name you're interested in. This seems like overkill. Is there anyway I can get the exact VM(s) I'm asking for without first retrieving everything?

```
String [][] typeInfo = new String[][] {new String[]{"guest", "config", "runtime"}};
ManagedEntity entity = new InventoryNavigator().searchManagedEntity(typeInfo, "hello-world-vm");
```

In debugging it's been found this single call returns all VM's listed and the API searches through that list to find the one matching the passed name. For performance reasons I'd like to NOT return every listed VM but only the "hello-world-vm".

Comment: Can you show us your code please?

Comment: Snippet has been posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something unique to locate the VirtualMachine you are looking for like its UUID.

For example:

```
ServiceInstance si = new ServiceInstance(xxx)
String uuid = "some uuid here"
VirtualMachine vm = si.searchIndex.findByUuid(null, uuid, true)
```

This will return only the VM that has the given uuid. The above code is groovy not Java, you would need to use semi colons and the getxxx methods in Java I think (Its been ages since I wrote actual Java)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I now have to make multiple calls to get the typeinfo (e.g. guest object, runtime object, config object, etc ..) whereas using the "searchEntities" route I get everything, literally everything, but also the typeInfo I want all in 1 call. Your route will get me the ManagedEntity object but then each subsequent call to "get config" or "get runtime" will result in an additional call ... that is unless I'm missing something obvious.  If we could get execute your method with typeinfo that would be wonderful but looking through the API I don't see it ...

Comment: In your question you asked: "Is there anyway I can get the exact VM I'm asking for without first retrieving everything?" My example hows how to get a vm object with out getting anything but that vm. So what exactly do you want? I can help you get it if I know what youre actually wanting.

Comment: You're correct and I should have been more clear in the question. I've since modified the above to reflect more accurately what I mean. We want to make as few trips over the wire as possible. We'd like to be able to ask for VM-ONE and VM-TWO in a single call whilst also grabbing their config, runtime, and guest objects. @Michael your way will get us the objects but the bare-bones version. Each subsequent call to "getConfig()" or "getRuntime()" will produce another call over the wire. We would like to get around that if possible.

Comment: Im not 100% sure if that is possible. Im going to dig in to see. Basically what you will need to do is get crafty with a search filter spec and a property collector. The part Im not sure about being possible is the grabbing specific VMs and only getting the properties about them. If for example both VMs were in a folder you could use a traversal and object spec and say I want these properties about virtual machines and start at this folder, then if that folder only had those 2 VMs in it you would get back what youre after, but its unlikely your inventory is laid out like that.

Comment: Also if you know python I have a sample I provided to the pyvmomi project using property collectors to get all vms and their info with minimal calls super fast. It can be found here: https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/vminfo_quick.py and then the actual property collector helper is here: https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/tools/pchelper.py  The vijava way of doing this is very similar.

Comment: Yea we've played a bit here and could not make anything happen. The least we can get things down to is 2 calls over the wire for a single specific VM with all required objects. I guess the bigger questions is: is it more performant to make 2 "smaller" calls or 1 "bigger" call? Don't yet know but we'll keep testing with our workload. And thanks for the link to the samples. I'll poke through them today to see what we can take away.

Comment: I have not been successful in making a sample that does what you're looking for. If you do happen to figure it out please share. I have a feeling this may be a limitation of the API. It really doesnt have the greatest search abilities when it comes to searches like this.

The best I could do was a property collector that would hit a given folder or datacenter and get back all VirtualMachines with a list of properties I set in my object spec.

Comment: yea same here :( i'll post back should anything turn up